# How to Flatten a semicolon Array properly in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Context: I've a data flow that extracts data from SQL DB, when data comes is just one column with a string separated by tab, in order to manipulate the data properly, I've tried to separate every single column with its corresponding data:

Comment: using flatten, the output data will have one row per item in each array.

Comment: ok, so what would I need to use to split it columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the derived column activity itself, try as below.

After the first derived column, what you have is a string array which can just be split again using derived schema modifier.

Where `firstc` represent the source column equivalent to your column `descripcion`

```
Column1: split(firstc, ';')[1]

Column2: split(firstc, ';')[2]

Column3: split(firstc, ';')[3]
```

[image]

Optionally you can select the columns you need to write to SQL sink

[image]

[image]